# Are All Variables in Clojure constant?

Tags: clojure

Is there a option to assign a value to a symbol in Clojure and then reassign the same symbol? What I see now is that all variables in Clojure are constant. Is it right?

Comment: Should have said it was Clojure! You should specify what you mean. In, say a `let` binding, you can create an `a` with the value of 1, use it, then change the value to 2. Anyone who used `a` prior to the change will still see 1. `def`s can have their value changed as well, although rarely is this ever something you want to do.

Comment: My terminology was incorrect, the answer here is right. Shadowing looks like a reassignment, but really it's a new value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Local names can be rebound:
- (Global) symbols can be rebound.
- There are several flavours of thing that (usually) a symbol can be
  bound to whose content is mutable:

  - [vars](https://clojure.org/reference/vars)
  - [refs](https://clojure.org/reference/refs)
  - [agents](https://clojure.org/reference/agents)
  - [atoms](https://clojure.org/reference/atoms)

These last each have different characteristics and purposes.

From [the above](https://clojure.org/reference/vars):

> Note - you cannot assign to function params or local bindings. Only
>   Java fields, Vars, Refs and Agents are mutable in Clojure.

Example of rebinding local name:

```
(let [coll (range)
      coll (rest coll)
      coll (filter odd? coll)
      coll (take 5 coll)]
  coll)
;(1 3 5 7 9)
```

Comment: can you give a code example of local names that can be rebound?

Comment: ...any use of `recur` with arguments is also rebinding names.

Comment: `let` in Clojure is like `let*` in other lisp languages. Every `coll` you make is a new binding that shadowes the old and does not rebind the original binding. As an example of that imagine this `(let [f (range) f (fn [] (first f))] (f))` The `f` captured in the closure is the one before the function gets the very same name and both exists.

Comment: @Sylwester The [docs](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#let) says of `let` *... the symbols ... are bound to their respective init-exprs ... . The bindings are sequential, so each binding can see the prior bindings*. It could usefully have added *but not the current one*. The bound *values* co-exist, but the bindings do not: the latter supervenes the former. Since the scopes are co-terminal, you can view this as shadowing, but you need not.

Comment: @Thumbnail my whole point is that a changed binding would then be reflected in the reference in the function. ` (let [f (fn [n] n) f (fn [n] (< n 2) n (+ (f (- n 1)) (f (- n 2))))] (f 10))` would be `55` if the `let` updates the same binding (making it a letrec) and `17` if it's a nested binding.

Comment: @Sylwester I'm afraid the new example adds nothing. Your interpretation is valid. So is mine. The earlier binding is never recovered, since it and the later one die together. How can we tell whether the earlier one is overwritten or obscured? There is no operative difference. And consider that `(let [f (fn [n] (if (< n 2) n (+ (f (- n 1)) (f (- n 2)))))])` does not compile - the function body can't find `f`.

Comment: Sylwester's point is correct. In his first example, the function bound to the second `f` is a closure, and it closes over the first `f` binding, but not the second. Reinterpreting the binding as changing value from the initial line that introduces it to the next invalidates the concept of a closure closing over certain locals in its lexical environment. Additionally, in implementation terms, the compiler creates new `LocalBinding` objects for each binding, whether it reuses a previously used name or not, and those objects are then used to determine which bindings are closed over.

Comment: Also note that at runtime, a "local" may have no representation whatsoever – for example in `(let [x 1 y 2] (+ x y))` you'd expect the constants `1` and `2` merely to be pushed on the stack and then an instruction to be executed to add them (or the compiler could go all the way and just inline the result as `3`). A local needs to be represented somehow at compile time, however, so that you can figure out things like which closures close over which locals, and for this purpose the identities of individual bindings of a `let` must be distinct whether or not their names are.

Comment: And finally, apart from the shadowing interpretation following naturally from an investigation of closures, the strategy that the compiler uses (introducing new locals rather than reusing existing ones) is directly observable from user code, although of course only at compile time (using macros), since as mentioned above, at runtime locals may not be represented.

Comment: And since you quote the [docs](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#let) on `let` in support of the rebinding interpretation, here's the final line: "Locals created with let are not variables. Once created their values never change!".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's a good point indeed, `recur` is a special case. NB. its semantics are meant to coincide with those of a self-call in tail position, and even for `loop` this is apparent in user code: (1) `(loop [x 1 f (fn [] x)] (if (== 1 x) (recur 0 f) (f)))` (evaluates to `1`), (2) `(loop [x 10 fs []] (if (pos? x) (recur (dec x) (conj fs (fn [] x))) (mapv #(%) fs)))` (evaluates to `[10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]`). ([Better formatting.](https://gist.github.com/michalmarczyk/1e624be27d6a6da690f2fdfbb47cb960)) (In implementation terms, this is more to do with closures than `loop` specifically.)

Comment: @MichałMarczyk I accept that the documentation is equivocal, and I take your word for how the compiler works. I still fail to see how this requires that each binding of a `let` must be regarded as establishing a nested scope. That the scope of the binding does not encompass its own expression - the basis of the examples involving closures - seems to me to be orthogonal. I have never known another programming language work this way. I am simply trying to conceive clearly and simply how clojure works. Perhaps I'll have an epiphany overnight. If so, I'll let you know :).

Comment: @Thumbnail Cheers. :-) Meanwhile I've been trying to approach this completely afresh and see how things work out if one assumes rebinding at the outset. For a start, it's clear that one has to conceptualize closures as closing over values rather than locals – not an outrageous idea, indeed that's basically how they work, although which values are used depends on which locals (as in, individual "`let` lines") are referenced. Then one has to distinguish "same" locals in a single `let` and in nested `let`s – unfortunate IMO, but maybe the "M" in "IMO" is important? ;-) Will ponder this some more.

Comment: Oh, one more thing re: other programming languages, in Scheme you can say `(let* ((f 1) (g (lambda (x) (set! f x))) (f (lambda () f))) (g 0) (f))`, and this evalutes to `0` (tested with Chez Scheme and Racket), demonstrating that the first `f` binding continues to exist independently of the second.

Answer (score 2):

All local variables – whether `let`-bound or `fn`-bound (`fn` parameters) – are constant, that's right. (They are like mathematical variables in that you can evaluate the expressions they're involved in under various assignments of values to variables, but during any single such evaluation the assigned value must be held constant.)

Note that such locals can be *shadowed* by identically named locals in nested scopes; the shadowing locals can have independent values, but they also cannot be reassigned.

There is also a distinct concept of Vars – the top-level objects most commonly introduced by `def` forms. These can have their root values rebound, and additionally, if marked `:dynamic`, can be rebound thread-locally.

Comment: so.. can we agree that the answer to my question is 'yes'? meaning that all variables in Clojure are constant?

Comment: @CrazySynthax, eh. atoms and refs aren't constant, and vars are only sorta-constant (they *can* be rebound, although it's good practice only at development time, not in production). And those aren't the only reference types -- you've also got agents and futures. Clojure has a significant set of tools for dealing with state changing over time, even if the Right Way to interact with that state is by rebinding new values, not modifying things in-place.

Comment: Minor point: you can shadow a local in the *same* `let` or `fn` scope: `((fn [n n] n) 3 5)` => `5`. Probably more confusing than its worth.

Comment: @CrazySynthax The thing is that the official docs – the documentation on the website and the docstrings – don't tend to use the word "variable"; in fact, the website even states that "Locals created with let are not variables. Once created their values never change!" This is of course contestable ("variable" is the standard word in mathematics and functional programming with no implication of the value actually varying over time), but the point is that we have to agree what the term refers to before an answer can be stated. If we define it to mean "local", then the answer is "yes".

Comment: @CrazySynthax If we want to include Vars, then the simple answer is "no", because it is possible to rebind them, and additionally dynamic Vars that are thread-locally bound can have their current binding replaced with `set!` (this is why `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)` works, for example).

Comment: @Thumbnail Yeah, agreed about `fn`. Re: `let`, I would say that each binding pair (symbol/destructuring form + the init expression) in a `let` introduces a new scope (though because of destructuring this still doesn't nail down the semantics completely, see http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1613 ). In contrast `letfn` puts all the bindings in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to follow the docs at:  http://funcool.github.io/clojurescript-unraveled/#state-management

```
    cljs.user=> (def x (volatile! 2))
    #'cljs.user/x
    cljs.user=> x
    #object [cljs.core.Volatile {:val 2}]
    cljs.user=> (deref x)
    2
    cljs.user=> (vreset! x 5)
    5
    cljs.user=> x
    #object [cljs.core.Volatile {:val 5}]
    cljs.user=> (deref x)
    5
```

But, I find all the stuff about "immutibles" conceptually incoherent.  Maybe someone more knowledgable can comment.